# newly graduate or new graduate

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Which one is correct?

> I am a *new* graduate and have been teaching German for a few weeks now.
>
> I am a *newly* graduate and ...

I can't decide whether to use "new" or "newly".

Comment: **New graduate** is more formal. 
>Example -An example format in preparing a resume for a new graduate. If you can decide it why are you asking that question :D

Answer (score 3):

"new graduate" is correct.

'New' is an adjective which describes the noun, 'graduate'.

'Newly' is an adverb which would describe a verb, but in this case, you need the noun.

Comment: *I'm a new graduate. I have newly graduated.* Just two examples to complete this answer.

Comment: Newly graduated is used a lot but it is slang. Type newly graduated in google and the first result will be **The BEST And WORST Cities For The Newly Graduated**

Comment: @speedy what is slang about "newly graduated"? It's perfectly valid English.

Comment: @simchona Perfectly valid doesn't mean correct. Show me a grammar rule that makes *newly graduated* correct. Something that can be valid for India or States not always is correct in UK. Phrase that is not correct but is used a lot is slang for me, because it is informal and some sort of dialect.

Comment: @speedyGonzales: The grammar rule that permits *newly graduated* is the one that also allows *newly hatched*, *newly published* and *newly discovered*. It definitely isn’t slang. Slang describes a type of vocabulary, not a type of grammar. Informal language doesn’t mean the same as dialect. Standard English is one of the many varieties of the language and it embraces both formal and informal styles.

Comment: Thanks for giving me some examples @Barrie England . Yes I know that there is difference between informal language and dialect. I was referring that that might be typical for a region. I am trying to stuck up with British formal English. Language is tool people use to communicate and hence it is influenced by their needs and their every day life so it embrace not only formal and informal styles, but many other things and language evolutes together with its speakers. Nice remark Barrie, thank you again.

Comment: Regarding the headline above referring to "the newly graduated", I think that's one of those cases where the noun has been omitted because the speaker thinks that it's implicit. "The newly graduated" could refer to humans students, dogs exiting obedience school, or a set of cylinders used for chemistry. The omission there has less to do with "the newly graduated" being a correct noun phrase and more to do with newspapers omitting words to save space.

Comment: "Graduated" is an adjective. So, it can be qualified by an "Adverb". But, "graduate" is a noun so it should be qualified by an adjective.

Answer (score 3):

As Nishant has already said, the correct usage is **new graduate** because of the adjective/noun relationship. A sample phrase for newly graduated would be something like:

```
Our firm has a number of entry-level positions available for newly graduated individuals.
```

Answer (score 0):

"New graduate" is correct. "Graduate" is a noun here.